# How add time to date

Tags: mysql, date, time

I have a date range parameter, need to split into multiple date, and each will have same time as the parameter.

Not sure what is the problem with `ADDTIME`, maybe Im missing a cast? I can solve it casting to string and concat but I guess should be easier.

**Current Output**

```
    selectDate  time(@s_date)   time(@e_date)   addtime(date(a.selectDate), time(@s_date))
1   2016-09-03  08:00:00        16:00:00        08:00:00
2   2016-09-04  08:00:00        16:00:00        08:00:00
```

**Desire Output**

```
    selectDate  time(@s_date)   time(@e_date)   addtime(date(a.selectDate), time(@s_date))
1   2016-09-03  08:00:00        16:00:00        2016-09-03 08:00:00
2   2016-09-04  08:00:00        16:00:00        2016-09-04 08:00:00
```

**Possible solution:**

```
CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(a.selectDate, '%Y-%m-%d '), 
       DATE_FORMAT(@s_date, '%H:%i:%s')) as start_time,
```

My big **[query](http://rextester.com/DUVOK57001)**

```
select a.selectDate,
       time(@s_date),
       time(@e_date),
       addtime(date(a.selectDate), time(@s_date))

from (
    select '1900-01-01' + INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a) + (1000 * d.a) + (10000 * e.a)) DAY as selectDate
    from (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as c
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as d
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as e
) a
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @s_date := '2016-09-03 08:00:00', @e_date := '2016-09-04 16:00:00') par
WHERE selectDate BETWEEN date(@s_date) 
                     AND date(@e_date)
```

Comment: Try like this .Select cast( concat(selectdate,' ',time) as datetime) .

Comment: Thanks @PrasannaKumarJ You are right that is simpler. Still wondering why can add using time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select a.selectDate,
       time(@s_date),
       time(@e_date),
       addtime(concat(a.selectDate,' ','00:00:00'),time(@s_date))

from (
    select '1900-01-01' + INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a) + (1000 * d.a) + (10000 * e.a)) DAY as selectDate
    from (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as c
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as d
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as e
) a
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @s_date := '2016-09-03 08:00:00', @e_date := '2016-09-04 16:00:00') par
WHERE selectDate BETWEEN date(@s_date) 
                     AND date(@e_date)
```

refer [this link](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions/addtime.php)